# Lebesgue-Stieltjes Measure of Closed, Open, and Semi-Interval

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let's say we're given a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\mu$ and an associated function $F_{\mu}$ such that $$\mu ([a,b)) = F_{\mu} (b) - F_{\mu} (a)$$ for all semi-intervals in $\mathbb{R}.$

I aim to calculate $\mu \left([a,b] \right), \mu ((a,b)), \mu ((a,b])$ in terms of the function $F_{\mu}.$

My current idea is to express the closed, open, and semi-interval in terms of the left semi-interval as such:

$$(a,b) = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} [a_i, b)$$ where $a < a_{i+1} < a_i$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$. For example, such a sequence could be $a_i = a + 2^{-i}.$

Then, $$\mu ((a,b)) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu( [a_i, b)) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(F_{\mu} (b) - F_{\mu} (a + 2^{-i}) \right).$$

We could get similar expressions using $[a,b] = [a, b+ \epsilon) \diagdown (b, b+ \epsilon)$ and $(a,b] = [a - \epsilon, b] \diagdown [a - \epsilon, a]$ and then substituting as needed.

However, all of these expressions would be extremely messy and would give very complicated answers. Is there a cleaner way of expressing the measure of each interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu ((a,b))=\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu ([a+\frac 1 n , b))=\lim_{n \to \infty}[ F_{\mu} (b)-F_{\mu} (a+\frac 1 n)]$. This is $F_{\mu} (b)-F_{\mu} (a+)$ where $F_{\mu} (x+)$ denotes the right-hand limit of $F_{\mu} (b)$ at $x$.

Similarly, $F_{\mu} ([a,b])=F_{\mu} (b+)-F_{\mu} (a)$ and $F_{\mu} ((a,b])=F_{\mu} (b+)-F_{\mu} (a+)$.

[It should be noted that $F_{\mu}$ is continuous from the left at every point and, as  a monotone function, has right hand limit at every point].

Comment: ok, thank you so much! since $F_{\mu}$ is only continuous from the left, that means the right-hand limit at $x$ doesn't necessarily equal $F_{\mu} (x)$ right? Whereas if we had the left-hand limit, it would equal $F_{\mu} (x)$?

Comment: @theGrind24 Yes, that is right.