Stieltjes Integration Problem

Consider a non-negative bounded function $f:[-R,R]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with infimum bounded away from $0$, and the function $g:[-R,R]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with $g(x) = x - \operatorname{sgn}(x)R$. Then $g(R) = 0$ and $g(-R) = 0$ while $g(R/2)\neq 0$ and $g(-R/2) \neq 0$.

Let $\mu_g$ denote the Lebesgue measure associated with $g$, i.e., $\mu_g([-R,R]) = g(R+) - g(-R-).$
We have that $$0\leq \int_{-R}^R fd\mu_g \leq \sup_{x\in[-R,R]}f(x)\int_{-R}^R d\mu_g =  \sup_{x\in[-R,R]}f(x)\big(g(R) - g(-R)\big) = 0.$$ On the other hand, $$\int_{-R}^Rfd\mu_g\geq \int_{-R/2}^{R/2}fd\mu_g \geq \inf_{x\in[-R,R]}f(x)\big(g(R/2) - g(-R/2)\big) > 0.$$
Obviously, both results contradicting. However, I don't see what went wrong.

$\mu_g$ is not what you wrote. It is the Lebesgue measure plus a Dirac measure in zero with mass $2R,.$

I don't understand. Here, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4378304/lebesgue-stieltjes-measure-of-closed-open-and-semi-interval the measure is defined just as in my Q. Could you please specify what precisely do you mean?

Too long for a comment.
That other post makes silent assumptions about the distribution function $F_\mu\,.$ We cannot just take any function $g$ and declare that
$$
\mu_g(a,b)=g(b)-g(a)
$$
defines a measure. Have you checked that in your case the measures of the intervals $[-R,0)$ and $[0,R]$ add up to the measure of $[-R,R]$ that you declared to be zero?
Hint: they don't.
Correct approach.
Your function $g$ is the difference of the two increasing functions
$f(x)=x$ and
$$
h(x)=\cases{-R\,,&$x\in[-R,0)\,,$\\+R\,,&$x\in[0,R]\,$}
$$
and therefore gives rise to a signed measure $\mu_g\,.$ The positive part of $\mu_g$ is obviously Lebesgue measure. Due to the jump of $h$ the negative part of $\mu_g$ is the Dirac measure of mass $-2R$ (fixing my initial sign error) in zero.

oh no, I see my problem! Thank you

@SydAmerikaner no problem. Jump functions are lovely. Enjoy.
